# main(String[] args) different of String[] args = {.....}?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, args

OK, here we go:
When I pass arguments through the static main, my program works fine. but when I pass the same "arguments" declaring inside main, doesnt works. If sounds confused, here's the code. All I want is to do these thing works with no args through main.
Here's the DEBUG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbGyo.png

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DoProcessBuilder extends Thread {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    DoProcessBuilder teste = new DoProcessBuilder();

    String[] uia = {"ls","-al","|","grep","bash"};
    teste.ExecCommand(uia);    // here this not works, WHY? if I execute the "java DoProcessBuilder ls -al | grep bash" works fine?

    teste.ExecCommand(args); // works fine!

  }

  public  String ExecCommand(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringBuffer x = new StringBuffer();
    if (args.length <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Need command to run");
    }

    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
    process.waitFor();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = "";

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        x.append(line+"\n");
    }
    System.out.println("\nCOMMAND OUT \n"+x.toString());

    return x.toString();

  }
}
```

Comment: please show us your stacktrace "not works" is not helping us

Comment: It should work. Like Philipp said, please post the stack trace.

Comment: print both array and check if they are equal

Comment: With the given information, the only thing I can say is that `uia` and `args` don't contain exactly the same strings. Use breakpoints to verify this.

Comment: IS this an exercise or do you really want to use this? Using external commands is not the java way of doing things! There is almost NEVER an urge to invoke external commands. For the given task, you may use File#listFiles() and filter on the received list of files.

Comment: Gyro, I dont want to list files, this is only an example. I want to control the OS through the shell. I debugged this in eclipse and checked. both args and uia vars are equal.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to execute a shell pipe with ProcessBuilder. That won't work. The pipe `|` is no valid argument for the `ls` command. You must start a shell `new ProcessBUilder("sh")`.

And it works fine with args because your program do not get the pipe and the rest from the calling shell. Your program only gets `ls -al`.

Comment: execute this programm with args ls -al | ... It works

Comment: If you execute `java DoProcessBuilder ls -al | grep bash` from a shell you never will get `|` `grep` `bash` into your program.

Comment: Peter, did you tryied to execute this programm?  compile these programm, exatcly as it is. go to your command/shell and execute java DoProcessBuilder ls -al | grep something . it works!

Comment: Of course you get some output, but this output is the list of files getting from your program (ls -al) and then your program stdout pipes into grep from the shell, where you issues the command in the example. Your program is not calling `grep` at all. Do a `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args))` and you see. Over.

Comment: You're right Peter . and I should do the ProcessBuilder as you mention. TNX!

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue, the place you are mention. But with `teste.ExecCommand(args);` you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
   StringBuffer x = new StringBuffer();
    if (args.length <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Need command to run");
    }

    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start(); // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    process.waitFor();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = "";

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        x.append(line+"\n");
    }
    System.out.println("\nCOMMAND OUT \n"+x.toString());

    return x.toString();
```

Comment: I know , if you execute with no args, it does that. Executes this with args like I mention.